# Docker failing to add remote file with 'too many redirects'

Tags: docker, boot2docker, confd

I'm trying to build the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu-debootstrap:trusty
ENV CONFD_VERSION 0.6.3
ENV CONFD_INTERVAL 30
ENV CONFD_NODE 172.17.42.1:4001
ENV CONFD_BACKEND etcd
RUN apt-get update -q \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -q nginx \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
ADD https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/releases/download/v0.6.3/confd-0.6.3-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/confd
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/confd /usr/local/bin/confd
EXPOSE 80
CMD confd -verbose -interval $CONFD_INTERVAL -backend $CONFD_BACKEND -node $CONFD_NODE
```

But it fails trying to fetch the remote file with a 'too many redirects' error:

```
$ docker build -t confdrouter .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  16.9 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu-debootstrap:trusty
 ---> 21530629f1e1
Step 1 : ENV CONFD_VERSION 0.6.3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 070ff91dc728
Step 2 : ENV CONFD_INTERVAL 30
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2d30a2f30f85
Step 3 : ENV CONFD_NODE 172.17.42.1:4001
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 96915c53a9aa
Step 4 : ENV CONFD_BACKEND etcd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5d770c929056
Step 5 : RUN apt-get update -q   && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -q nginx   && apt-get clean   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5c2465522a1c
Step 6 : ADD https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/releases/download/v0.6.3/confd-0.6.3-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/confd
2014/11/07 11:31:57 Get https://s3.amazonaws.com/github-cloud/releases/13234395/5e2257d4-4f46-11e4-92c7-d029c6449976.3-linux-amd64?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dconfd-0.6.3-linux-amd64&response-content-type=application/octet-stream&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1415381577&Signature=WWdGHk8K3%2BIQyl7Cl4UcBN8aDQM%3D: dial tcp: lookup s3.amazonaws.com on [10.0.2.3]:53: too many redirects
```

Running boot2docker 1.3.1 on Mac OS X 10.10. Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error is coming from DNS, and the DNS server is at 10.0.2.3.  This is the address that VirtualBox maps for DNS.

Very similar question at [How to fix Docker's "Error pulling image...too many redirects" failures while pulling images from registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060099/docker-failed-to-pull-images-from-registry), with advice to use Google's DNS at 8.8.8.8, which is generally excellent.