# (spotify) Maven docker builder for Java

Tags: java, maven, docker

I'm trying to build docker image for Java using (spotify) Docker Maven Plugin.
But while running `mvn package docker:build` on my project, I'm constantly getting the following error:

> Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.2.6:build (default-cli) on project gs-spring-boot-docker: Exception caught: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/java/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.1.2.2:53: no answer from server -> [Help 1]

Comment: Looks like a network error. Maybe you need to configure a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Problem related to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060099/docker-failed-to-pull-images-from-registry)

Easiest solution possible is 
`boot2docker restart` if it works, otherwise there is temporary workaround.

```
osx$ boot2docker up
osx$ boot2docker ssh
docker@boot2docker$ sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
docker@boot2docker$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

> It works until reboot.