# Docker push fails, too many redirects

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have a repo on dockerhub. I have successfully pushed to it several times. Now, suddenly I can't push. I can't imagine the small XML file edit causing the problem, but I don't know what it might be.

The command and error are as follows:

> Pushing tag for rev [6c4dcead2bef] on
>   {https://cdn-registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/lulumialu/titandb/tags/latest}
>   2015/06/22 13:17:10 Put
>   https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/lulumialu/titandb/images: dial
>   tcp: lookup index.docker.io on [10.0.2.3]:53: too many redirects

Comment: Sounds like an ephemeral problem with Docker's servers to me.

Comment: try restarting boot2docker

Comment: @nathaniel-waisbrot It wouldn't surprise me if it was a problem with docker's servers, that's a pretty common theme in my interactions with dockerhub's registry ;)

Comment: Hitting same problem today...

Comment: @LaurenWolfe The workaround here seems to work for now http://stackoverflow.com/a/24710550/486688 Just be sure to stay logged into boot2docker after updating /etc/resolv, then docker login from another window.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan. I ended up just building and pushing from one of my linux servers :/ It works, but what a pain! I'll give this a try next time.

Comment: @Jonathan -- Give the fix I came up with a try if the problem persists for you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some prodding, I came up with a solution that works for me (the others didn't, so if you have no luck with those, give this a try). It appears to survive a reboot, so slightly less of a pain too.

```
$ VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" poweroff
$ VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natdnshostresolver1 off
```

More info here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat_host_resolver_proxy

Comment: I encountered this same problem today trying to pull an image down from docker.io, and this modifyvm did the trick. Oddly there doesn't seem to be any way in VirtualBox to change the DNS resolution, which would be nice. Thanks for sharing the solution!

Comment: Thanks!  Saved my day!